# Is there an upper bound on number of logistic regression responses that yield infinite estimates

Tags: regression, logistic, bounds, separation

Suppose a logistic regression problem has N observations of {0, 1} and that there are p parameters.  Also assume the design matrix, X, is full rank with p < N.  We know that there will be certain response vectors Y where the ML solution does not exist (X can completely separated the response).  I'd like to know if there is an upper bound for how many of these might exist.  It's totally a function of the design matrix.  I can work out an explicit formula for p = 2 and I think for p = 3 it is N^2 - N + 2 (related to the cake sequence).  Both of these are pretty small compared to the 2^N possible response vectors.  I've been searching the literature to see if there is a closed form solution for p > 3 and I can't find anything.

The problem is related to convex polygon partitioning on the unit sphere in p-dimensional space since the regions where the data can be completely separated are intersections of N p-1 dimensional half spaces.  Each half space through the origin is defined by the subspace orthogonal to a row of X...hence there are N of them.  What is the maximum number of these convex polygons that can be generated by intersecting N p-1 dimensional half spaces?

Comment: One can plausibly search the surface of the p-dimensional unit sphere and identify the exact number for a given X.  You just pick a point and scale it larger and larger.  It will always converge to one of the responses that can be separated by X.  You will then find all such special responses.  But this is brute force and for large p it becomes prohibitive.  But it's faster than checking all 2^N responses.  I'm surprised there is not an elegant way to find these corners of the unit cube of all responses.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you know a lot about the covariate distribution and how 0s & 1s are distributed across them,  the answer is no.  You can always theoretically have all 1s for some particular combination of explanatory variables and zero for the rest.

I guess one condition is "enough observations per factor combination that all 0s or all 1s is only so likely for whatever you assume to be plausible response probabilities".